# php - how to catch error "Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded"

Tags: php

I can't seem to catch this just by using PHP. This is what I did:

```
$maxFiles = (int)ini_get('max_file_uploads');

if ($maxFiles < count($_FILES['name'])) {
    echo 'ERROR';  
}
```

But `count($_FILES['name'])` is always equal to `$maxFiles` (if the error occurs). 
And I really don't want to change the condition to `==` ... it doesn't seem right.

Comment: @stevether: it wouldn't change anything. That error is thrown before user runtime

Comment: oops edited. That was just my typo

Comment: @Austin: no, php throws that error. And condition `$maxFiles < count($_FILES['name'])` will never be true

Comment: @zerkms, you're right. so do you have a way to catch this error?

Comment: Tried it with try { _upload_ .. } catch (Exception $e) { do something.. } ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exactly you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @take: lol, what is `upload`?

Comment: @Austin: isn't that obvious? OP gets error message thrown by php, and he doesn't want it to be thrown

Comment: @take: that is quite a sneaky way. I'll try it now

Comment: @BPm: actually I don't believe it is possible to handle that

Comment: @Austin: placeholder for **what**? Uploading is performed by php **before** user runtime. You don't have a chance to wrap `upload process` in `try {}` because it is already done even before your first line of code is evaluated. I don't even mention that native php errors aren't exceptions and cannot be processed with `try - catch`

Comment: @Austin: what is "upload function"? Are you sure you completely understand how php handles file uploading?

Comment: @Austin: it's not "uploading function". I recommend you to read manual: http://php.net/move_uploaded_file "Moves an **uploaded file** to a new location". Or even read the function name

Comment: @BPm: on production you just turn off `display_errors` and don't care of this particular "issue", which is not an issue at all

Comment: @zerkems And _I_ recommend that _you_ stop being so aggressive to a fellow answerer. I did not understand the asker's goal at first, and though he was trying to preform a typical file upload with `move_uploaded_file`. Ok, you were right. I understand PHP perfectly fine, just did not catch right away what the problem was that the OP was dealing with. I can read just fine. `move an already uploaded file`.

Comment: @zerkms ignore this error? but then the user wouldn't know that their files haven't been uploaded properly

Comment: @BPm: don't show more inputs than you can handle. You know the limit before the page is shown - so use it

Comment: @Austin: you first started being sarcastic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532592/php-how-to-catch-error-maximum-number-of-allowable-file-uploads-has-been-exce#comment15246601_11532592. So you got what you wanted

Comment: @zerkms it's a bit more complicated than that. Since the user has two options, upload the files or do something else... Maybe javascript is the way to go for this one I guess

Comment: @BPm: well the solution is: don't show on the client more inputs than you can handle. As simple as it is.

Comment: everyone please calm down... I appreciate all your help

Comment: @Austin: "By the way, take meant upload as a placeholder, but im sure you could figure it out, it was *obvious*" --- *this* was sarcastic. You wanted to joke about "obvious" word - well, the joke didn't work

Comment: @Austin: it wasn't sarcasm in my case. I seriously asked if it is obvious or not (because it is, otherwise I wouldn't ask that).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the use-case is exactly, but from your question it seems that the user / visitor can add file-upload fields to the form.

What you could do in that case, is put the value of `$maxFiles` in a javascript variable and simple not add new fields when the maximum is reached.

Comment: @zerkms True, but without more context (yes / no javascript, used libraries, etc.) it's impossible to give more details.

Comment: alright, if there's no way to catch this using PHP, I'll just use javascript

Comment: @BPm Why would you want to catch it using php? Using javascript gives instant feedback where using php would probably require the post request to complete. Not a good idea with my Internet connection at least :-)

Comment: @jeroen I just think that it'd be cleaner at my end... sigh

Comment: @BPm How are you building the form / adding the file upload fields, using javascript or php?

Comment: @BPm: it would be cleaner and it would be nice to handle it in php as well, but php doesn't give you a chance of doing that (at least I cannot figure out any). So in this particular case you just don't have choice

Comment: @jeroen I build the form using php

Comment: @zerkms, yeah I've been searching for this solution for a long time and I thought it was just because I don't know how to do it. Now that you guys confirm it. Thanks. I'm writing the js function now

Comment: @BPm With a complete reload / rebuild when the user adds an additional field? In that case you can also always limit the number of fields presented based on your `$maxFiles` value in just php.

Comment: @jeroen: not in case of malicious user. That's why server-side handler would be nice

Comment: @BPm But to be honest it's all just speculating without knowing what you are doing exactly :-)

Comment: @jeroen, it's just because there are two choices for the user, either upload a file or let the app create it for them. The inputs shown depends on what they did previously

Comment: @zerkms True, server-side handling always wins in that case.